# Where to find Deployment group Tab in TFS 2017?

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-deployment

We have **TFS 2017 update 3** configured on our environment and I want to create a deployment group in which I can perform same deployment tasks on multiple machines\servers through release definition but i am not able to find the Deployment groups tab under the Build & Release hub. There are only 5 tabs present under Build and Release hub-
**Builds,
Releases,
Packages,
Library,
Task Groups**

So, i want to know does **TFS 2017 update 3** has the deployment group feature or not? If yes, then from where can i create the deployment groups?

Comment: Hi PatrickLu-MSFT, I used Agent Phase option to perform same deployment tasks on multiple machines\servers present in release definition but this feature takes time for deployment to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Deployment group targets feature **only available with TFS 2018 and later**.

As workaround, on earlier version, you have an option of installing multiple agents. Please note, multiple agents can run the deployments in parallel and can overstep on each other for shared resources.

If the application needed to be deployed to multiple servers, the Windows PowerShell remoting had to be enabled manually, the required ports opened and the deployment agent installed on each of the servers. The pipelines had to be managed manually if a roll-out deployment was required.

Besides you could also upgrade TFS server version to get more new features.

Answer (score 0):

Deployment Groups are supported only in TFS 2018 & VSTS.

You can see the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=vsts).

Comment: So, is there any other feature similar to Deployment groups in TFS 2017 update3, except task groups?